# how to change feature of capsule collider in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

I hope my question 's not duplicate.
I need to change feature of capsule collider in runtime 
my code :

```
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.AddComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider));
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().center.y = 0.17f;Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().radius = 0.72f;
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().height = 0.64;
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().direction = 2;
```

But i get

```
`Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.CapsuleCollider.center'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable`
```

error.
Please help me .

Comment: I'm very Amateur in  unity3d...i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`CapsuleCollider.center` is `Vector3`. You can't modify a property of `Vector3` that is declared as auto-property in another class. Make a copy of it, modify the y-axis then assign it back to the `CapsuleCollider.center`.

Also, `CapsuleCollider>().height` is a float, you need to add `f` at the end of 0.64f to make that compile.

```
//Make a copy
Vector3 center = Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().center;
//Modify the copy's y axis
center.y = 0.17f;
//Apply to the target object
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().center = center;

Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().radius = 0.72f;
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().height = 0.64f;
Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ().direction = 2;
```

---

There is no need to use `GetComponent` each time so you can just cache that `CapsuleCollider` since it is a class, it will store the reference:

```
//Get CapsuleCollider collider
CapsuleCollider cCollider = Game_Controller.Database [m, n].Nute_M.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ();
//Make a copy
Vector3 center = cCollider.center;
//Modify the copy's y axis
center.y = 0.17f;
//Apply to the target object
cCollider.center = center;

cCollider.radius = 0.72f;
cCollider.height = 0.64f;
cCollider.direction = 2;
```